# Custom Toolbar in Detail grid of KendoUI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to create custom tool bar in detail grid of kendo-UI Grid. i have created the icons through tool-bar template.But i cant hook up with jQuery events. Someone could you please help me?

Comment: Please, show the code so we don't have to write a full example from scratch.

Comment: Try to make an available scenario describing your problem. You may use an existing JSFiddle like this one [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dimodi/SDFsz/)